# Laravel returning array from each() method

Tags: laravel, closures, each

I am getting an array of permissions related to the roles of a specific user, mainly as a way to get my head around working with eager loading and the each() method

When creating a $permissions array in this manner, how would I actually be able to access the array outside the closure?

```
$user = User::with('roles.perms')->find(1);

$permissions = array();

$list = $user->roles->each(function($role) use($permissions)
{
    $permissions = array_merge($permissions, $role->perms->toArray());
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just pass the `$permissions` variable by reference:

```
$user->roles->each(function($role) use(&$permissions) { //<-- passed by reference
    $permissions = array_merge($permissions, $role->perms->toArray());
});
```

Notice the `&`, now you have the same variable declared outside the function and it's in your current scope and modified inside the closure. SO, you can use the `$permissions` here, for example:

```
dd($permissions); // dump and die
```

Comment: Ah, right. The closure copies into scope by default. Thanks for that!

Comment: This answer is useful for me as well this time, but just that array merge didn't work as expected, so I changed to something like this `$permission[] = $role->perms->toArray();`